# How to find overlap of lists in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, algorithm, loops, overlap

I have this get_over_lap function I found on stackoverflow:

```
def get_over_lap(a,b):
    return max(0, min(a[1],b[1])-max(a[0],b[0]))
```

This will return the overlap of two lists, for example:

```
ovl = get_over_lap([30,74],[10,47])
-> Overlap is 17
```

How do I iterate through a list like this to determine the overlap of all the small lists inside and return a new list of overlap

```
[[4, 43], [9, 47], [76, 122], [30, 74], [10, 47], [81, 125], [84, 124], [47, 90], [1, 38]]
[30, 74] [10, 47]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's an "overlap" exactly, please? Are inner lists always strictly increasing? What output are you expecting on the larger list and what code are you stuck on in computing it? Seems like `[get_over_lap(x, y) for x, y in zip(lsts, lsts[1:])]` might work?

Comment: Overlap here basically means the values that lie in both lists(intersection). I want to determine the overlap of the 1st one and the 2nd, the 3rd and the 4th, the 4th and the 5th and so on

Comment: Wow thank you it really helped me out!!!

Comment: I just forgot the zip my mind is a whole mess right now